# Unable to connect to AWS rds instance after ssl certificate updated to rds_2015

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I updated my AWS rds instance with new ssl certificate but i am unable to connect through node.js

CA file http://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CA File in that link is a bundle of 11 certificates. You need to seperate them and then use them in CA field for mysql module in nodejs. Otherwise mysql module in nodejs is updated with new certificate. You can use their inbuild certificates also.